# Alternative to IBM WebSphere DataPower XML Security Gateway XS40

Tags: security, ibm, web-services

Is there any alternative to [this IBM solution](http://www-01.ibm.com/software/integration/datapower/xs40/features/?S_CMP=rnav) for a SOAP security gateway?
Maybe open source software or hardware from other vendors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cisco has a comparable product - the ACE XML Gateway:

http://www.cisco.com/en/US/products/ps7314/

Web-based policy creation tool, content mediation, WS-* security support etc. etc.

Answer (score 1):

*Updating this 2009 question with March 2011 info...*

Cisco [announced the end-of-life](http://www.cisco.com/en/US/prod/collateral/contnetw/ps5719/ps7314/end_of_life_c51_609816.html) for their ACE XML Gateway on August 1, 2010 with a last-ship-date of April 30, 2011 and support tapering off through January 2016.

In addition to the Forum Systems [Forum Sentry](http://www.forumsys.com/products/soagateway.php) and Vordel [XML Gateway](http://www.vordel.com/products/gateway/index.html) products mentioned in other answers, two other vendor's products to consider are:

- Layer 7 [SecureSpan SOA Gateway](http://www.layer7tech.com/products/xml-gateway-overview)
- Intel [Expressway Service Gateway](http://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/intel-application-security-and-identity-products-service-gateway/) (formerly known as the *SOA Expressway*)

Answer (score 0):

Forum Systems has their Sentry product. You can check then out here [Forum Systems](http://www.forumsys.com)

Answer (score 0):

The [Vordel](http://www.vordel.com/) XML gateway has similar features to the IBM product. The main advantage with Vordel is that you can extend the product using real programming languages (not just [XSLT](http://www.ibmpressbooks.com/articles/article.asp?p=1313997)!). It sold as either a hardware appliance or software (which is supported as either a physical or virtual installation).